# the best way to deal with Sound in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, audio

is it best to load sound files into the library, or to load them externally? What I want to do is make a sampler app. You'd have a selection of loops and drag and drop them onto a timeline. My main concern is performance and any delay of sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a big initial download is not a problem for you, then put them in the library. It's easy and you won't have to do any loading or unloading stuff, apart from showing load progress for the app itself.
If you have a LOT of sounds and don't want the users to only be able to use your application after all sounds are loaded, load them seperately after the user chooses which samples are needed.

I don't think it makes a difference in performance after all needed sounds are loaded one way or the other.

For flexiblity, I would go for seperate download because once you release a newer version of your app, all sounds that were already loaded before by users won't have to be re-downloaded again. Adding more sounds would be possible without even the need to recompile another version of your app, if you first load a separate list of available samples.

Comment: thanks a bunch. it sounds like a separate download is the way to go, since it's looking like the end product will have a lot of sounds. However, I'm pretty sure each sound loop will be of a very small file size, like 60-90 loops, each 2-4 seconds long.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the project. If it's a website with music then I would load it with XML and LoaderMax.

If it's a game I would embed internally and load on game launch. Choosing what to load internally like game sounds and externally like music which I would stream in.